# Лишние знаки при делении float/double c++

Tags: c++, float, double

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float comission = 0, minsumm = 0;
    cin >> comission >> minsumm;
    comission = comission / 100;
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        float temp;
        cin >> temp;
        sum += temp;
        double proc = temp * comission;
        if (proc >= minsumm) sum +=proc;
        else sum += minsumm;
    }
    cout << std::fixed << setprecision(2) << sum;
    
}
```

К нему у меня есть пара вопросов. Почему при `comission = comission / 100` `3 / 100` становится `0.0299999993`? Почему введенное `1.20` в переменную `minsumm` с клавиатуры становится `1.20000005`?
Вернее, почему так я знаю, но не знаю как исправить это. Можно было просто обрезать все знаки после какого-нибудь четвертого знака, т. к. дальше расчетов в задаче точно не будет, но тогда `3 / 100` станет `0.0299` вместо `0.0300`.
А округление в задаче всегда должно быть (все после второго знака после запятой число должно округляться вниз), но если округлять тот же пример то `comission` будет `0.02`, а не `0.03`.
Еще я читал про decimal, но в c++ в стандартных библиотеках его нет, нужно что-то качать, а в задаче разрешено использовать только стандартные библиотеки.

Comment: Вообще-то при выводе все нормально округляется (https://ideone.com/H2t4Wt). В чем тут проблема?

Comment: В бухгалтерии этот вопрос уже решён. Всё считается в копейках. В компьютерах в дробных числах сразу появляются маленькие ошибки, а при вычислении целых чисел - нет.

Comment: но формат на выводе обязательно должен быть с двумя знаками после запятой

Comment: может вам на bcd код перейти?

Answer (score 1):

Если брать вопрос почему, то чтобы сэкономить Ваше время предлагаю ознакомиться с [этим](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0U8Ddx4TgE) видео.
Если брать вопрос как починить, то для этого уже существует решение. Это эпсилоны. Они являются что-то вроде погрешности при вычислениях типов с плавающей точкой. К счастью, стандартная библиотека C++ уже имеет такие константы. К примеру, для типа `float` имеется константа `FLT_EPSILON`. Соответственно всё что нужно вам перед округлением - это добавлять константу к числу.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    float num{0.2999999999f};
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << num + FLT_EPSILON << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Помимо этого думаю следует добавить что это также может зависеть и от компилятора. Лично по моему опыту при работе с GCC такой проблемы не было, но при работе с LLVM фронтендом, возникали те же проблемы. Дело в том что подобные модификации может вносить, либо программист, либо компилятор. Но лучшая практика - это писать код, который будет работать на всех компиляторах и системах.

Comment: Когда я считаю comission, в одном из примеров оно 100, и чтобы считать комиссию от чисел нужно разделить его на 100, чтобы потом умножать и получать проценты. В случае с comission = 3 после деления оно становится 0.2(9), а после добавления FLT_EPSILON становится еще более страшным 0.030000119209289550...

Comment: Я вам написал написал пример в случае с 0.029. В случае 100, вам нужно сравнивать значение с эпсилоном. Число 0.030000119209289550 это 0.03 с округлением до 2-х цифр. Я подумал это то что Вы хотели. Или я неправильно понял задачу?

Comment: Я еще немного почитал, получается что в double и float вообще никак не получится хранить 0.3 ровно? Суть задачи в том, чтобы ровно подсчитать все комиссии. Задача проверяется с помощью тестов, и при comission = 0.0299999999999999 не проходит около 6 тестов из 51, а при этом значении около 35. Значит, лишние знаки после запятой будут препятствовать правильным ответам на остальных тестах. А есди округлить все до 3х знаков, число снова превращается в 0.0299999999999.
К сожалению, у меня нет всех тестов, и я не могу проверить, где конкретно ломается программаю

Comment: Да, всё верно. Здесь как и везде. Всегда есть погрешность ;)

Comment: И нет никакого типа, в котором памяти выделялось достаточно, чтобы хранить 4 знака после запятой совсем без погрешности? float и double могут держать огромные числа, в задачах входные данные редко превышают 5 знаков после запятой

Comment: Такой принцип работы у чисел с плавающей запятой. В видео помомне объяснялось, что в результате получается бесконечные 0 и 1-цы. Максимум что можно сделать - это увеличить точность. К примеру, `double double` Я честно говоря не помню (да и никогда не использовал) есть ли в c++ тип `real`, но в других языках программирования он есть. Это тип зависимый от процессора. Минимум он `double`. Максимум что может позволить процессор. Но это я так, к слову. В данном случае это никак не повлияет на результат. В смысле подобная точность ничего не поменяет.